# Form submitting creating an 500 error

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to make this form work. But when I click submit it goes to at 500 internal server error.
Am I doing something wrong here or am I way off?
I've tried everything that was obvious changed post action even tried changing the submit button action.
This is my script for the form action.

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="signup"; // Mysql username 
$password="pass"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="signup"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="signup_mysql"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get values from form 
$venue_name=$_POST['venue_name'];
$production_company_name=$_POST['production_company_name'];
$venue_contact_name=$_POST['venue_contact_name'];
$location=$_POST['location'];
$office_location=$_POST['office_location'];
$capacity=$_POST['capacity'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
$facebook=$_POST['facebook'];
$twitter=$_POST['twitter'];
$soundcloud=$_POST['soundcloud'];
$website=$_POST['website'];



// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(venue_name, production_company_name, venue_contact_name, email, location, office_location, capacity, age, description, facebook, twitter, soundcloud, website)VALUES('$venue_name', '$production_company_name', '$venue_contact_name', '$email', '$location', '$office_location', '$capacity', '$age', '$description', '$facebook', '$twitter', '$soundcloud', '$website')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='index.html'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?> 

<?php 
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Look at your server error logs - that will tell you what is going on.

Comment: 500 normally means parse error - or deprecated `mysql` functions maybe

Comment: @scrowler Using deprecated functions generates a Notice or a Warning, but is not fatal.

Comment: File does not exist: /home/sinlabel/public_html/signup/sys_cpanel, referer: http://108.165.22.98/~sinlabel/signup/insert_ac.php

Comment: That is the error I am getting

Comment: I guess you need to get rid of that "~".

Comment: that is just the cpanel account name

Comment: It may not be a fatal error, but the deprecated mysql_* functions are a huge issue.  Prepared statements in mysqli or PDO are much more secure.  Your code as written is wide open to injection attacks.